# how to keep text aligned when adding a button next to it

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a little problem, the buttons on my table are not aligned. because I added another button next to it.

```
<td class="row-right" >
    <i id="spinner-deploiement" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" *ngIf="statut == 'In progress'" routerLink="application/{{Id}}"
            aria-hidden="true" style="color: #01AA7B; padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;"></i>

    <a class="btn btn-success btn-round" style="padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;" 
            routerLink="application/{{Id}}" *ngIf="statut == 'ok'"></a>

    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-round" style="padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem; text-align: right; font-size:12px;" 
            routerLink="application/{{Id}}" *ngIf="statut == 'ko'"></a>

    <button class="btn" style="padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;" routerLink="/demande" 
            *ngIf="statut== 'waiting'"
            (click)='canceled(demande)' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="canceled" >
            <i class="fa fa-ban fa-ban"></i> 
    </button>
</td>
```

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f26hyl

Comment: can you please share any fiddle or plunker link

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f26hyl   I would like "waiting" to be on his column

Comment: [Did none of these work for you at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=align+text+to+button) Or did you not search first? [ask]